# If a container or pod exceeds its memory limit(OOMKilled-137), Does that Pod get rescheduled to another Node or what happened?

Tags: .net, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks

Base on my understanding about Kubernetes ,if pod consumes more memory than it mentioned limit.
E.g. If mentioned limit is 128Mi,But Pod try to consume memory > 128Mi
Then it becomes crashloopback and after that if memory consumption not reduced it becomes "OOMKilled" status. that is handled by Linux kernel. My confusion is after pod become OOMKilled ,does it reschedule in to the same node or different node or its already killed and not recover back?

I tried it with my aks cluster. I saw pod become crashloopback and finally OOMKilled. But after that I could not see any new pod created in the node. Please someone explain what is the next recovery mechanism that Kubernetes use to recover this pod?

```
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "64Mi"
          cpu: "0.1"
        limits:
          memory: "128Mi"
          cpu: "0.3"
```

Comment: Your "deployment YAML" seems to actually be a link to an image file.  Can you [edit] the question and include any relevant source code directly in the question and in plain text?

Comment: OOM kill happens when Pod is out of memory and it gets killed because you've provided resource limits to it. You can see the Exit Code as 137 for OOM.

When Node itself is out of memory or resource, it evicts the Pod from the node and it gets rescheduled on another node. Evicted pod would be available on the node for further troubleshooting.
Refer doc- 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#exceed-a-container-s-memory-limit

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/

Comment: @Arko Thanks for your answer. Yes Pod eviction happens when Node not-ready and faulty. and it will be resheduled to another node which is healthy. That is decided base on concerns like tolerationSeconds and default taints  values of the Node. But my concern is if Pod become OOMKilled it means that Pod is finished. No recovery again and Killed?

Comment: if the pod's RestartPolicy is set to Never, then the pod will not be rescheduled and will remain in the OOMKilled state. Check your pod's restart policy.

Comment: @Arko Thankx a lot. It means I have two conclusions                                                                      1.  Pod will be rescheduled to another node when Node not -ready status happened        2.  Pod will be rescheduled to another Node when "OOMKilled" happened also                     Is this controlled by same  Kub Scheduler in the control plane  or Node Controller or Kubelet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pod eviction happens when Node not ready and faulty. and it will be rescheduled to another node which is healthy. That is decided based on concerns like toleration Seconds and default taints values of the Node.
`OOMKilled`  will only be reported for containers that have been terminated by the kernel OOM killer. It's important to note that it's the container that exceeds its memory limit that gets terminated (and by default restarted) as opposed to the whole pod (which can very well have other containers). Evictions on the other hand happen at the pod level, and are triggered by Kubernetes (specifically by the Kubelet running on every node) when the node is running low on memory*. Pods that have been evicted will report a status of  `Failed`  and a reason of  `Evicted`.

Details about the reason can be seen in the Kubelet events for pod evictions

You need to verify the details run

```
kubectl describe pod [name]
```

[image]

It should show something like this along with reasons under events.

Coming to your question- *Will the pod get reschuduled or stay dead* depends on its `node.kubernetes.io/not-ready` and `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable` tolerations and `RestartPolicy` You can verify your restart policy under spec.template.spec.restartPolicy

Reference-

[Deployments | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#pod-template)

[Exceeds memory](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#exceed-a-container-s-memory-limit)

[Pods reschedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766989/does-pods-get-rescheduled-if-kubernetes-node-gets-killed-due-to-power-failure)